# How to force FormAuthentication to refresh the users roles?

Tags: asp.net, security

I'm trying to figure out how when using the default asp.net forms authentication stuff one can change the roles that a user has dynamically.  In our case a user has access to many accounts and there roles can change per account.  This doesn't seem like rocket science to me but I can't figure out I would do this.  Does anyone have a experience trying to do this or a link that would be helpful?

UPDATE:

Just to clarify.  We know at startup that User X has access to account #1 with roles 1,2,3 and account #2 with roles 1,2.

So first off I have to handle this part of the problem.  Getting their roles based off their current account.  For this I think I'd use a RoleProvider.  The problem I'm trying to solve though is once ASP.Net has a User how do I tell it to invalidate that user or refresh that user so it would hit my custom RoleProvider (or what not) again.

Comment: Maybe you aren't thinking your roles through enough. It sounds like you have 1 application. Under that application you have many users and many accounts. Users and accounts have a many to many relationship, with X users having Y permissions to Z accounts. I don't know if Roles alone will provide you the functionality you need, as opposed to a database solution that lists UserID, AccountID, Role in a table. Then you can query that table when a user tries to access an account, and allow/disallow/hide/show data and operations.

Comment: We have all that stuff.  Which is why we would need to create our own role provider.  But then we're back to how do we tell the security stuff that it needs to refresh the roles the person has (from our role provider which we'll have put into the config).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles.AddUserToRole() should take care of adding the user to a role.

For removing: Roles.RemoveUserFromRole()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roles.aspx